# Select distinct value with where clause for a datatable

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have a datatable. I am getting distinct value of column from below code.

`AllFields` is my datatable.

```
var distinctIds = AllFields.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => new
    {
        id = s.Field<string>(ColumnName),
    })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

however I want to get distinct value of a column with where condition on same column. I have tried below thing.

```
var distinctIds = AllFields.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => new
    {
        id = s.Field<string>(ColumnName),
    })
    .Distinct()
    .Where(f => f.id.Contains(TxtStringSearchInput.Text))
    .ToList();
```

it is showing me below error on run time.

> nullreferenceexception error . {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Psychic debugging says that one of your rows has a `null` in it and the Contains is failing.  However, without an actual error message my psychic skills have been known to be lacking.

Comment: @SteveMitcham is probably correct - check out the linked question for _lots_ of information about this error and how to track down where it is.

Answer (score 3):

As you are getting NRE. It looks like one of the value is coming `null` so you should be checking for **null** as well in `Where()`:

```
var distinctIds = AllFields.AsEnumerable()
.Select(s => new
{
    id = s.Field<string>(ColumnName),
})
.Distinct()
.Where(f => f.id !=null && f.id.Contains(TxtStringSearchInput.Text))
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're getting a null reference exception on the second call, and the only difference is that you're calling `Contains` on the `id` field, it is most likely that the `id` field is null for one of your comparisons.

Try checking for `null` before calling `Contains`, for example:

```
var distinctIds = AllFields
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => new {id = s.Field<string>(ColumnName),})
    .Distinct()
    .Where(f =>
        f.id != null &&
        f.id.Contains(TxtStringSearchInput.Text))
    .ToList();
```